# quicksort too slow when sorting triangles

Tags: java, 3d, render

I want to build a 3d render engine from scratch in java. The code works fine, I only have some problems sorting the triangles in the right order, so that they won't get rendered over one another. I have implemented face culling and quicksort to sort the triangles by the average z value of the 3 vertices.

Anyway for now it works but I figured out once the amount of triangles comes closer to 100k the sorting algorithm seems to take extreme amounts of time so that the program is unusable.

Here is my code for sorting the triangles. I followed this scheme: https://www.baeldung.com/java-quicksort. I have changed it a bit because in my case I load a .obj file, where the faces are only the references to the vertices (in another list). So it's quite confusing **but it works**.

```
public static ArrayList<Vector> sortList(ArrayList<Vector> array,
            Vector[] vectors, int begin, int end) {
        if (begin < end) {
            int partitionIndex = partition(array, vectors, begin, end);

            sortList(array, vectors, begin, partitionIndex - 1);
            sortList(array, vectors, partitionIndex + 1, end);
        }
        return array;
    }

    public static int partition(ArrayList<Vector> arr, Vector[] vectors,
            int begin, int end) {
        float pivot = vectors[(int) arr.get(end).x - 1].z;
        pivot += vectors[(int) arr.get(end).y - 1].z;
        pivot += vectors[(int) arr.get(end).z - 1].z;
        pivot /= 3;

        int i = (begin - 1);

        for (int j = begin; j < end; j++) {
            
            float check = vectors[(int) arr.get(j).x - 1].z;
            check += vectors[(int) arr.get(j).y - 1].z;
            check += vectors[(int) arr.get(j).z - 1].z;
            check /= 3;
            
            if (check <= pivot) {
                i++;

                Vector swapTemp = arr.get(i);
                arr.set(i, arr.get(j));
                arr.set(j, swapTemp);
            }
        }

        Vector swapTemp = arr.get(i+1);
        arr.set(i+1, arr.get(end));
        arr.set(end, swapTemp);

        return i + 1;
    }
```

and here I calculate the positions and vertices etc.

```
Vector[] vectors = new Vector[obj.vertices.size()];
        Vector[] vectors3D = new Vector[obj.vertices.size()];

        // transformation and rotation

        for (int i = 0; i < obj.vertices.size(); i++) {
            Vector vertex = obj.vertices.get(i);
            vectors[i] = Calc.matmul(Calc.rotationY(rotY), vertex);
            vectors[i] = Calc.matmul(Calc.rotationX(rotX), vectors[i]);
            vectors[i] = Calc.matmul(Calc.rotationY(rotZ), vectors[i]);

            vectors3D[i] = vectors[i];

            // projection
            float depth = 1 / (z + camera.z - vectors[i].z);
            float[][] projection = { { depth, 0, 0 }, // Orthographic:
                                                        // depth instead
                                                        // of 1/camera.z
                    { 0, depth, 0 } // Perspective: 1/camera.z isntead of
                                    // depth
            };
            vectors[i] = Calc.matmul(projection, vectors[i]);
            vectors[i].mult(size);
            vectors[i].add(new Vector(x, y))
                    .add(new Vector(camera.x, camera.y));
        }

        // drawing

        if (type.equals(Object.CORN)) {
            for (int i = 0; i < vectors.length; i++) {
                triangles.add(new ArrayList<Vector>());
                triangles.get(triangles.size() - 1).add(
                        new Vector(vectors[i].x, vectors[i].y));
                // point(vectors[i].x, vectors[i].y);
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Object.MESH)) {

            for (int i = 0; i < obj.faces.size(); i++) {
                Vector corner = obj.faces.get(i);
                float x1 = vectors[(int) corner.x - 1].x;
                float y1 = vectors[(int) corner.x - 1].y;
                float x2 = vectors[(int) corner.y - 1].x;
                float y2 = vectors[(int) corner.y - 1].y;
                float x3 = vectors[(int) corner.z - 1].x;
                float y3 = vectors[(int) corner.z - 1].y;
                triangles.add(new ArrayList<Vector>());
                triangles.get(triangles.size() - 1).add(new Vector(x1, y1));
                triangles.get(triangles.size() - 1).add(new Vector(x2, y2));
                triangles.get(triangles.size() - 1).add(new Vector(x3, y3));
            }
        } else if (type.equals(Object.FILL)) {

            ArrayList<Vector> faces = obj.faces;

            // sort back to front
            faces = Calc.sortList(faces, vectors3D, 0, faces.size() - 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < faces.size(); i++) {

                Vector corner = faces.get(i);
                float x1 = vectors3D[(int) corner.x - 1].x;
                float y1 = vectors3D[(int) corner.x - 1].y;
                float z1 = vectors3D[(int) corner.x - 1].z;
                float x2 = vectors3D[(int) corner.y - 1].x;
                float y2 = vectors3D[(int) corner.y - 1].y;
                float z2 = vectors3D[(int) corner.y - 1].z;
                float x3 = vectors3D[(int) corner.z - 1].x;
                float y3 = vectors3D[(int) corner.z - 1].y;
                float z3 = vectors3D[(int) corner.z - 1].z;

                float nx = (y2 - y1) * (z3 - z1) - (z2 - z1) * (y3 - y1);
                float ny = (z2 - z1) * (x3 - x1) - (x2 - x1) * (z3 - z1);
                float nz = (x2 - x1) * (y3 - y1) - (y2 - y1) * (x3 - x1);

                Vector lightVector = new Vector(light.x, light.y, light.z)
                        .normalize();
                Vector normalVector = new Vector(nx, ny, nz).normalize();

                // face culling
                if (Calc.dotProduct(new Vector(0, 0, -1), normalVector) < 0) {

                    int col = (int) Calc.map(
                            Calc.dotProduct(lightVector, normalVector), -1, 1,
                            0, 255);
                    colors.add(new Color(col, col, col));

                    x1 = vectors[(int) corner.x - 1].x;
                    y1 = vectors[(int) corner.x - 1].y;
                    x2 = vectors[(int) corner.y - 1].x;
                    y2 = vectors[(int) corner.y - 1].y;
                    x3 = vectors[(int) corner.z - 1].x;
                    y3 = vectors[(int) corner.z - 1].y;

                    triangles.add(new ArrayList<Vector>());
                    triangles.get(triangles.size() - 1).add(new Vector(x1, y1));
                    triangles.get(triangles.size() - 1).add(new Vector(x2, y2));
                    triangles.get(triangles.size() - 1).add(new Vector(x3, y3));
                }
            }
        }
        this.repaint();
```

the .obj file follows these rules:

v x y z (v indicates vertex)
[...]
f [vertex index]/[texture index]/[normal index] [vertex index]/[texture index]/[normal index] [vertex index]/[texture index]/[normal index] (for a triangle)

so when i have
v 0 0 1
v 0 1 0
v 1 0 0
f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3

i get the triangle vertices with (f arraylist of arraylist of vectors) f.get(0).get(0).x f.get(0).get(1).y f.get(0).get(2)

I hope that is understandable

Comment: Are you using `java.util.Vector`?

Comment: no i use my own vector class but it just hold x,y,z as floats and has basic vector mulitplication

Comment: So you've written your own quicksort. How do you avoid the cases where quicksort is slow, like when sorting a list that's already sorted (or almost sorted)?

Comment: I don't. I guess thats also a big problem. How would I do that? Loop through the list and checking if it is sorting before the sorting algorithm?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that sorting triangles is bound to have a huge performance hit and if it isn't needed (e.g. due to transparency) engines normally rely on the z-buffer and accept the overdraw.

In general 100k rendered triangles is a lot for a pure software rendering engine. So instead of trying to speed up your sort you might want to try and reduce the number of rendered triangles:

- calculate a potentially visible set (pvs) of triangles that are within the camera's view frustum
- try to use more sophisticated pvs mechanisms to cull objects behind walls etc.
- try to reduce the size of the view frustum if possible (don't render too close or too distant objects)
- try to use level of detail rendering (LOD), i.e. use lower resolutions for distant models and maybe even just billboards for the most distant
- use backface culling to remove invisible triangles *before* sorting your triangles

Also note that you might not have to sort all triangles each frame. If the camera or other objects don't move too fast or pop into or out of existence you could try to reuse the already sorted triangle list for a couple of frames - or you could try to sort only a portion of the elements.

Additionally you could try not to sort by average z but use min/max z for the triangle, i.e. the vertices. Calculating average z has a performance hit as well

Comment: Wow I am really surprised someone understood my mess. Thank you very much I knew of all these things but have never considered implementing them. Thanks again :) Edit: Grüße aus München

Comment: @Luis you're welcome :) - I actually didn't try to understand your "mess" but just had a quick glance - especially at your comments ("read the code the documentation lies" might often be true but good documentation and comments make it so much easier and faster to grasp the meaning of a piece of code :) )